# Send the name of image files

Tags: image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm sending image files using `image_transport` and my client node likes to receive the file names as well but apparently [`sensor_msgs::Image`](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html) doesn't have a field for it. Nor I haven't been able to find other measure in ROS to send image file and its name together.
What's the most recommended way to achieve my goal? Extend `Image` and make my own publisher node (isn't it nicer to have this feature by default if it doesn't exist)?

To save an image as a file btw usually requires file extension but knowing file name solves as well ([`sensor_msgs/CompressedImage`](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CompressedImage.html) has a field for it but still not for file name).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42309/send-the-name-of-image-files/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2012-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Before trying these, first maybe you should ask yourself if you *really* need to be sending images with filenames over ROS, instead of just the filenames, and letting your client read them into memory. However, if you really *must* do this, there are two options that come to mind:

**Option 1:**
You can publish two streams of data, one from the image_transport and one from a normal publisher with your own custom metadata type with an identical header. Then on the receiving end, you should be able to use a message synchronizer with the image_transport as described in [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/9705/synchronizer-and-image_transportsubscriber/).

**Option 2:**
If you care about the image data frame-by-frame, then you're probably only using the RAW transport of image_transport. In this case, you don't really need it, and you can just use a normal publisher and use your own composite message like:

```
sensor_msgs/Image image
string filename
```

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2012-08-29**:
@jbohren I asked this b/c I wasn't sure if there's already nice solution for my case. msg synchronizer looks interesting & I'll try it.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2012-08-29**:
Also nice warning at the beginning! In our case we receive msg from a node on different robot that's made by other team in different org so 1st of all nice to have flexibility (and I can think of situations where sending file names becomes advantageous).